# Add HTML code on top of PHP based page which is utilized by an Android App

Tags: php, html, web

I have a php script page which has all server side stuff.My android App utilizes this php page in order to access database and perform different functions.

I tried to add this page as a front page of my website and add some HTML code to make it look nicer.

Now i have both HTML and PHP code on same page which is the front page of the website.
After doing this my android app was not able to get to php code of the page thats need to perform certain tasks and as result app crashed.

So i wanted to know if its possible to do something like this or not? And if it is possible than can anyone please tell me whats the best way to do it?

I tried to do it but it failed.
Thank You!!

Comment: Hard to understand what you mean ... it's not unusual to have an HTML page with embedded PHP code blocks.

Comment: @dbaseman thank you for the response.i have a index.php page which has only php code.Server side script which is on that page is utilized by an android app. for e.g when i go to activity A it populates the activity with data which app got it from external database using index.php page.Now when i go to my actual website from browser where i have this index.php page its just blank.So i wanted to add some HTML to it so when i go there i see some HTML template instead of blank white page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys but i solved it by adding 'if else' statement in my php code and in the 'else' part of the 'if else' statement i assigned a php variable the whole code HTML template code and i echo it afterwards.

I made my android app checks for a 'tag'
If the tag is 'android' it executes the part of the code which is in if statement and if tag is not 'android' than it executes the else part of the code.

Here is what i did:

```
if(tag == 'android'){
//performs all the operations required by android app
}else{
//displays html template and ignore everything else
$htmlcode = '<html>...</html>';
echo $htmlcode;}
```

Thank you all for your valuable input :)

Answer (score 2):

you tring to do all your work in one file. Instead you can created two different  files. One can use as webservice for your android app which contain all functions to accept input from andorid device and if require return json encoded result. Other file contain your site view part on web browser. This will be easy to manage.

Comment: thank you for the response.yes i can do this.But im being greedy here sorry :) bcoz If i have both the things on the same file and if i put it up as a main page of my website than my website will register more hits no?

Answer (score 1):

Is a bit hard to understand what you mean, but from what I gather, you're trying to execute some particular pho code on a web page to be used by your Android app.

First you should make sure the php code is executed only if the browser is an Android device (and not if it's just someone pulling up the page on their computer).  In order to do this, you need to have php check the browser's user agent:

```
$ua = strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
if(stripos($ua,'android') !== false) { 
  //PHP Code for Android Here
}
```

Once you have that check done, any php that is inside that If statement will only be executed if you access the site from your Android device. Optionally, if you don't want to serve a page if the browser isn't Android, you can just add an `else` block after the above code and redirect or die.  I'm a bit fuzzy on the rest of your problem but hopefully the above code block will help.

Have a look at this page: [Android Detection with JavaScript or PHP](http://davidwalsh.name/detect-android) for more info on detecting Android Browsers in web pages using php or JavaScript.

Comment: thanks for the response.This just detects whether a website is access from a browser of android phone or not.I tried to display the html template on 'else' of that 'if' statement.it works but only at browser level.Android app still crashes :S